# Shiny proxy : Connect to localhost:2375 failed - Connection refused

Tags: docker, shinyproxy

When I am trying to start application in shinyproxy I get the following error
`Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:2375 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refus`ed)

- OS - rhel 7.1

**Docker.service file**

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd-current \  
        /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -D -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 \    
        –add-runtime docker-runc=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-runc-current \  
        –default-runtime=docker-runc \  
        –authorization-plugin=rhel-push-plugin \  
        –exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=systemd \  
        –userland-proxy-path=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-proxy-current \
```

Comment: Please, add information about how do you launch your docker container (params, dockerfile, whatever you have)

Comment: Docker container is working fine but when trying to do the same using Shinyproxy its not able to start. Shinyproxy is not able to connect to docker daemon.

Comment: Please, when I ask for more information about your docker container launching, is that is important to help you. Don't answer that is running. Maybe it's running without `--net=host` or whatever. When someone that is trying to help you ask for more information, I should give it. That's only a piece of advice.

Comment: I don't know if you really understand Shinyproxy(Its a application). Shinyproxy does the job of launching the docker container. So i don't directly launch the docker container. To test it outside shinyproxy I use **"sudo docker run -it -p 3838:3838 openanalytics/shinyproxy-template"** to launch docker container.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please go to Docker settings and and expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS.